# Ubuntu install on Chromebook ARM (samsung)

Tags: chromebook

Alright so I installed the crouton Ubuntu thing on my Chromebook while following [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vpDtD4eKBB4). After getting it installed it would not let me set a password and now I can't update the system so I'm wondering how to fix it. I'm kind of noobish at this.

This is what is displayed-

```
(precise)redeyeschivo@localhost-$ sudo password set
[sudo] password for redeyeschivo:
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply type in your password, which will not appear, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.